# Trigger status bar notification in doInBackground() method?

Tags: android, asynchronous, notifications

I'm getting the following reports from users of my app:

```
class java.lang.RuntimeException
Msg: android.os.AsyncTask$3.done:200 (An error occured while executing doInBackground())
```

The only thing I'm doing that might be causing the errors is attempting to trigger a status bar notification when there is an error encountered. Can I do this in the `doInBackground()` method or can I only do this in the `onPostExecute()` method?

Here's some code...

in my `doInBackground()` method, I call the following function in the `catch` portion of my `try/catch` blocks:

```
private void triggerNotification(String contentText) {
            mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) thisContext.getSystemService(ns);
            if(contentText == null) {
                contentText = "Sync complete.";
            }
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(thisContext, SomeOtherClass.class);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(thisContext, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(thisContext, tickerText, contentText, contentIntent);
            mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }
```

Comment: Does it happen every time `triggerNotification()` is called from `doInBackground()`? And do you have anymore of the stack trace from the runtime exception?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have additional stack trace. I haven't been able to reproduce the error so far. I'm unsure if triggering the notification is considered interacting with the UI, which I know you can't do in the `doInBackground()` method.

Comment: These are the exceptions I'm tracking:

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
     triggerNotification(e.getMessage());
     return false;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
     triggerNotification(e.getMessage());
     return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
     triggerNotification(e.getMessage());
     return false;
    }

Comment: What about good ol' "Catch(Exception e)" ?